# Get progress of an animation - SpriteKit SKAction

Tags: swift, skaction

The following code runs a sequence of images.

```
let powerBar:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()

func animate(){
    var textures:[SKTexture] = []
    for i in 1...30 {
        textures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "power\(String(format: "%04d", i))"))
    }
    let animation = SKAction.animateWithTextures(textures, timePerFrame: 0.03)
    powerBar.runAction(animation)
}
```

if then the animation was stopped by the following code

```
powerBar.paused = true
```

**Is there a way to know at which moment the animation stopped at, maybe in form of percentage of the whole animation?**

**Background:** I am working on a simple game. The user can set a firing power by tap-start and tap-stop a moving power bar. This is why I need to know the progress of the animation. Ideas, thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the approach I finally do, it's ugly, but it works

**Assumption:** The total number of images for the animation is known

First, I made an extension for NSString

```
extension NSString{
    func stringWithinCharPairs(str:String, char:String) -> String{
        let range = str.rangeOfString(char)!
        let str2 = str.substringFromIndex(range.endIndex)
        let range2 = str2.rangeOfString("'")
        return str2.substringToIndex(range2!.startIndex)
    }
}
```

Here I make use of the `powerBar.texture!.description` property. 
It would return something like `"<SKTexture> 'power0008' (120 x 120)"`

```
var str:NSString = NSString(string: powerBar.texture!.description)
str = str.stringWithinCharPairs(str as String, char: "'")
```

Here **str** will give you **imageNamed** of the texture for the given SKSpriteNode.

According to the question, **str** can be "**power0008**" or any texture that is being applied at the moment where `powerBar.paused = true` is run.
Because the total number of the images is known, knowing the current name of the texture will help getting the progress or percentage of the animation has played.